# How to properly use reduce with a dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, reduce

I am using a custom function as part of a reduce operation. For the following example I am getting the following message `TypeError: reduce() takes no keyword arguments` - I believe this is due to the way I am using the dictionary `mapping` in the function `exposed_colum` - Could you please help me fix this function?

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from functools import reduce


def process_data(df: DataFrame):
    col_mapping = dict(zip(["name", "age"], ["a", "b"]))

    # Do other things...

    def exposed_column(df: DataFrame, mapping: dict):
        return df.select([col(c).alias(mapping.get(c, c)) for c in df.columns])

    return reduce(exposed_column, sequence=col_mapping, initial=df)


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("app").getOrCreate()
l = [
    ("Bob", 25, "Spain"),
    ("Marc", 22, "France"),
    ("Steve", 20, "Belgium"),
    ("Donald", 26, "USA"),
]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1]), country=x[2])).toDF()

people.show()
process_data(people).show()
```

`people.show()` is looking like this

```
+---+-------+------+
|age|country|  name|
+---+-------+------+
| 25|  Spain|   Bob|
| 22| France|  Marc|
| 20|Belgium| Steve|
| 26|    USA|Donald|
+---+-------+------+
```

And this is the expected output

```
+------+---+
|     a|  b|
+------+---+
|   Bob| 25|
|  Marc| 22|
| Steve| 20|
|Donald| 26|
+------+---+
```

Comment: Could you please check people.show()?

Comment: sure, I just added the `show()` statement in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` does not take keywords, that’s true.
Once you remove the keywords, you’ll notice a more serious issue though: when you iterate over a dictionary, you’re iterating over its keys only. So the function in which you're trying to batch rename the columns won’t do what you had in mind.

One way to do a batch column rename, would be to iterate over the dictionary’s `items`:

```
from typing import Mapping
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def rename_columns(frame: DataFrame, mapping: Mapping[str, str]) -> DataFrame:
    return reduce(lambda f, old_new: f.withColumnRenamed(old_new[0], old_new[1]),
                  mapping.items(), frame)
```

This allows you to pass in a dictionary (note that [the recommendation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) for adding type hints to arguments is to use `Mapping`, not `dict`) that maps column names to other names. Fortunately, `withColumnRenamed` won’t complain if you try to rename a column that isn’t in the `DataFrame`, so this is equivalent to your `mapping.get(c, c)`.

One thing I’m not noticing in your code is that it is dropping the `country` column. So that’ll still be in your output.